# mongoDB and JSON Ref. or Pointer

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a question about mongoDB which supports JSON yes, I got the idea that you came through like JSON JSON pointer referencing a kind of foreign key relationship could develop.

Or am I wrong here?
CouchDB supports indeed this JSON Referencing

Maybe I can help as one of the background constraints in implementing document-oriented databases may nevertheless.

Comment: MongoDB is a BSON store, it stores JSON only in string form not as a queriable structure.

Comment: ok thx and Global lock -> DB Lock  Collection Lock and maybe Sub Collection Lock
Journal
Wait for 'ack' (bald default) for Consistency ?

Comment: MongoDB only has one write lock as of v2.0, DB level write lock. Journal Writes hold the top level write lock.

Comment: So I mongoDB provides no options ensure the integrity or consistency? Except on extra applications or application layers? Are there extensions or plugins for it?

Comment: I am unsure how my last reply was translated to that. MongoDB provides no relational integrity, basically you can't expect relational integrity in a non-relational model. MongoDB provides consistency and integrity of single rows, not only that but it also provides a journal, it is just that MongoDB only has a DB level write lock (and also an atomic one). If you wanna test consistency you will need to setup replica sets with different balancers and writing to different parts such as majority or only primary and what not, look more here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/ first